# slot to right click menu action does does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have written the below code to which I finally managed to add menu but connecitn menu to a function doesnt seem to work:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore

FILE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MainDialogWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainDialogWindow,self).__init__()
        ui_file = os.path.join(FILE_LOCATION, "example.ui")
        self._ui = uic.loadUi(ui_file, self)
        self.registerCallbacks()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        """Initialize the UI.
        """
        self.textBrowser.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

    def registerCallbacks(self):
        self.textBrowser.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu)
        # self.connect(self.textBrowser, QtCore.Signal('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)'), self.context_menu)

    def context_menu(self, pos):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        action = menu.addAction("clear")
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
        action.trigered.connect(self.clear)

    def clear(self):
        """Slot to claer text.
        """
        print("clear")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainDialogWindow()
    window.show()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 300)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

please helpp,, I want call the clear function from the right click menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to understand how the menu.exec_() method works, that method blocks the execution of sequential tasks until the user selects a QAction from the QMenu. In your case, for example, until when you press "clear" and the triggered signal is emitted (note: you have a typo), but at that moment there is no connection, so the clear method will not be called. The solution is to make the connection before invoking the QMenu exec_():

```
def context_menu(self, pos):
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
    action = menu.addAction("clear")
    action.triggered.connect(self.clear)
    menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
```